# Given a curve, such as $1/x$, how to find which tangent is closest to its OWN interception with the y-axis

Tags: calculus

As title mention, if I have a function such as $\dfrac{1}{x}, x>0$, how can I find which tangent of the curve is closest to its y-axis interception.

Using pythagorean theorem, one sees that the distance between a point $P(x,y)$ and its $x$-axis interception is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Eqn:

$$y(x) = \frac{1}{2} k x \left(\frac{\left(\frac{x}{L}\right)^{-1/k}}{1-k}+\frac{\left(\frac{x}{L}\right)^{1/k}}{k+1}\right)+\frac{k\,l}{k^2-1}$$

Where $L$ and $k$ are constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:** the distance from the point on the curve to the $x$-intercept of the tangent is
$$
\sqrt{y^2+(y/y')^2}
$$

[image: a curve and its tangent and the x-intercept]

---

**Hint 2:** the distance from the point on the curve to the $y$-intercept of the tangent is
$$
\sqrt{x^2+(xy')^2}
$$
[image: a curve and its tangent and the y-intercept]

Comment: Oh wait, I messed up didn't I? I meant the y-intercept.. I think. (A point lying on the y-axis, i.e. $x=0$).

Answer (score 1):

Tanget at $(a,1/a)$ is

$$y-\frac1a=-\frac1{a^2}(x-a)$$

The interception with $X$ axis occurs when $y=0$:

$$x=2a$$

Now, the distance from $(a,1/a)$ to $(2a,0)$ is
$$\sqrt{a^2+\frac1{a^2}}$$

It is well-known that the sum of a positive number and its inverse is minimum when the number is $1$, that is, $a=1$. The minimum distance is, thus, $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: And what if the function was a bit more.. complex. I didn't expect the trick at the end, I only put up $1/x$ because it was easier to work with than my original equation, which is: (Read body text Edit)

Comment: If it is more complex, this is esentially the same method, but finding the minimum by algebraic means can be difficult or impossible. You can always try numerical methods, if that fits your needs.

Comment: Oh yes, numerical methods. I would love that, how can that be done for my curve? I'm sorry If I'm asking too much, it's just that I've been trying to solve this for sooo long. I am okay with using Mathematica :)